# Why is our 1000 MB database file not uploading completely via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

We have an e-commerce Magento site and a large database of 1000 MB for that site.

When we try to import the database through phpMyAdmin, it's not uploading the full databse, a lot of tables will be missing after uploading.

We use a GoDadddy cPanel and phpMyAdmin.

How can we upload the full 1000 MB database completely?

Also, is there any way to replace the old domain name to new domain name in the database?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

For Export:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [db_name] | gzip > [filename_to_compress.sql.gz]
```

For Import:

```
gunzip < [compressed_filename.sql.gz]  | mysql -u [user] -p[password] [databasename]
```

Note: There is no space between the keyword '-p' and your password.